# How to refresh view within a FrameLayout included in a DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Basically I have a drawer with a button in it. When I click on the button I want to hide a view (another button) that is loaded in the FrameLayout.
Below I include the XML code for the drawer. The button is not included there because it is generated dynamically within the code. 
I tried getting the frameLayout and invalidating the view, but it does not seem to work. I think it is somehow related to the fact that it is loaded in a Fragment.

Any clue is more than welcome! Thanks!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/home_frame"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/home_layout" />
   </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: All you want to do is hide the second button (the one generated programmatically) ?

Comment: Not really. The button generated programmatically lives in the DrawerLayout. It has an onClick event associated that should hide a button which lives in the home_layout.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, got it working. I thought there was some hidden magic related to the fact of using FrameLayout, but not. The method is completely the same. Find the solution below:

```
        View view;
        if ((view = findViewById(R.id.bottomSet)) != null) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.invalidate();
        }
```

Note that "bottomSet" is defined within the FrameLayout that is being imported.